# Facenet and single image forward propagation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets, facial-identification

I have jumped into my project and I got stuck immediately. I do not see anything clear online regarding forward propagating other than they take a whole dataset and use it on their models.

The idea of my project is to recognize faces and compare their output vectors, as Facenet's last layer is a 128 dimensional array of a facial embedding. People online have only been propagating datasets but for the sake of my own practice I want to just directly take a face and see its output, but I don't know how to do this.

So far this is what I have and again I am stuck:

```
import tensorflow
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')

pic = load_img('trump.jpg')
pic = img_to_array(pic)
pic = np.expand_dims(pic, axis=0)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I do not know where to go from here. I have my image into an array but I am lost

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
model.predict
```

??

https://keras.io/models/model/#predict

Comment: I was unsure if I was able to use this, but perhaps I can use it. The `x` parameter in `predict()` is maybe where I can put my variable `pics`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with Seth's answer. It was a bit confusing at first, the initial code I posted didn't work, but now it does what I want. The way I've been doing this is just piecing example code from online and from tutorials and putting it to my use.

```
import tensorflow
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img 
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5', compile='False')

pic = load_img('trump.jpg', target_size=(160,160,3))
pic = img_to_array(pic)

pic = pic.reshape((1, pic.shape[0], pic.shape[1], pic.shape[2]))
pic = preprocess_input(pic)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
output = model.predict(pic)
print(output)
```

From what I know, FaceNet outputs a 128 dimensional array [?] and I'm now having trouble interpreting what all of this means. I'll look online but if someone can provide human assistance that'd be great

```
[[-0.36650193  0.07450597 -0.11253849  0.09382331  0.65579426  1.2289288
   0.7981924  -0.43557873 -0.9650308  -2.4071848   0.73522866 -1.2488084
  -0.7643076   0.97527826 -0.6454712  -1.3645316   1.0456135  -1.6320316
   0.5565866   0.09845503  0.7503164  -3.154975    0.6703275   2.3669581
   0.11742923  1.5341481   1.865606   -1.3307446  -0.632361   -1.6581261
   1.158609    1.8743702  -0.5332592  -0.06612988 -0.8802324   1.5062594
   1.9927465  -1.6820407   0.84190995  1.4670922   0.5759155   0.4494674
   0.35184044 -0.8682072  -1.1785389   2.2496219   0.9702482   0.5559205
  -1.5887636  -1.8496605   1.0645783   0.42627138  1.6334398   2.0875866
   0.05197076  3.3503294   0.46358824 -2.07692     1.5033835   1.7825121
   0.38589296  1.4082223   1.6586784   0.44597477 -0.39349917 -0.01715486
   2.3880703   0.05123563  0.6001561   1.7848682   0.57936746  2.2707727
  -0.17195459  1.8396529  -1.4007891   1.2714268  -0.41032675  0.64929354
  -1.7332536  -1.9563283  -0.52206075  0.866758   -0.6876267  -0.7875931
   0.9024028   0.6540389   1.4121637  -1.8792673   1.3698239   0.43517247
   0.1034093  -0.71052015  0.3376826   0.13816951 -0.9559467   3.2945871
   1.916734   -1.4701567   1.2339087   1.7374766  -1.2939825  -1.2702736
   1.970353   -0.5688637   1.004023   -1.9100393  -2.5775273   2.8778517
   1.4665067  -1.4564868  -1.6789169  -1.0139952   1.7792807  -1.4399014
  -1.2965738   1.1995381  -1.2554456   2.3882952   0.13599804 -1.6818564
  -0.5534592  -1.4732366   1.5166222  -0.28499228  0.96933156  0.4853603
   0.8890593  -2.5222735 ]]
```